# How to calculate 2790**2753 ≡ X (mod 3233)

Tags: math, rsa

I was doing RSA private key decrypt,but this big number always give me infinite or NaN,how to calculate it programmably?

Comment: infinite or NaN? for a start, don't use floating point...

Comment: Letting us know the language will be helpful.

Comment: have try js,python and c.

Comment: It's not about  floating point and language.

Comment: Just multiply 2790 by itself 2753 times, and then take the remainder on dividing by 3233.

Comment: Python → `pow(2790,2753,3233)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big integers are not primitives in most programming language, but many of them have a BigInt or BigInteger class.

Usually, there are specialized implementation for speeding up that power/modulus operation, rather than a simplistic implementation.

You have to specify the desired programming language for suggesting a complete bit integer library.

Comment: ok,I solve this using big int module, thanks.

Comment: You don't want or need to use a bigint package for this. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) for the right way to do it.

Comment: it is ironic that the suggested wikipedia page has a lot of references to bigint libraries at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#In_programming_languages

Comment: No need to use big numbers because, following basic rules of modular arithmetic, this bash script returns the answer: `ret=1;for i in {1..2753};do ret=$((ret*2790%3233));done;echo $ret`. The result is 65.